# setting chart size to fixed value in JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

In JFreeChart graphics, if you resize the application window, the graphics are repainted according to the application window size. Is it possible to set the chart size to fixed values?

Answer (score 0):

Well.
I would like to suggest a different approach. Without worrying to fix it in jfreechart graphics, I think you can easily do it using a java swing layout (e.g: `GridBagLayout`) .

Add the `ChartPanel` to a swing Panel and set the layout to `GridBagLayout`.
Hope this helps..